# subselect as column in a DB2 query

Tags: subquery

I made a query where I use a subselect of the same original select, but with a different condition from the original, I can not execute because this error appears:

> "A COLUMN OR EXPRESSION IDENTIFIED IN A HAVING CLAUSE IS NOT VALID SQLCODE = -119, SQLSTATE = 42803, DRIVER = 4.22.36 "

How can I correct this query?

```
SELECT A.COL1, 
       count(A.COL2) AS YYY, 
       sum(A.COL3) AS XXX, 
       (SELECT count(COL1) AS WWW 
        from SCH.TAB01 
        where COL4=A.COL4 
          AND COL5=A.COL5 
          AND COL1=A.COL1 
          AND COL4 = date(days(current date) - 1) 
          AND COL3 > 5 
        GROUP BY COL1) AS OOO 
from SCH.TAB01 as A 
where A.COL4 = date(days(current date) - 1) 
GROUP BY A.COL1
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `GROUP BY COL1` in the subselect

BTW you don’t need `date(days(current date) - 1)` a simple `CURRENT DATE - 1 DAY` would suffice.

Comment: Hi, l tried, but appears this message: "NO AUTHORIZED FUNCTION NAMED A.SUM HAVING COMPATIBLE ARGUMENTS WAS FOUND. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=4.22.36"

Comment: Maybe open a new SO question iwth your new SQL. You don't have `A.SUM` in your posted SQL so you have a different syntax error.

Comment: Or you could change `a.sum` to `sum`